# How do I do multivariate regression analysis in Python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, regression

I run the following simple code with the following hypothesis:

The A value and the B value are similar to each other, and the B value is made to be equal to the A value by combining several variables.

so my hypothesis is like this

A = W1(weight)*B + W2(weight)C(anotehr varables)+...

and here is my try code

```
hypothesis = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X1, W1)+tf.matmul(X2, W2)+tf.matmul(X3, W3)+tf.matmul(X4, W4) + tf.matmul(X5, W5) + b1)


cost = -tf.reduce_mean(Y * tf.log(hypothesis) + (1 - Y) * tf.log(1 - hypothesis))
train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.000000000000000001).minimize(cost)

predicted = tf.cast(hypothesis > 0.5, dtype=tf.float32)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(predicted, Y), dtype=tf.float32))

with tf.Session() as sess:
   # Initialize TensorFlow variables
   sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
   for step in range(5000):
       sess.run(y, feed_dict={X1:ct, X2: temperature, X3:humidity, X4: windspeed, X5:tideheight, Y:sst})
```

However, when I validated the value of this code, I came up with a value that did not fit at all.

It does not seem linear when I look at the dataset.

I would be grateful if you could give me an example for this situation.

my dataset:

```
 A         B             C              D         E       F
25.6    27.29999    24.4752741667   71.5801495  6.468   97.1
25.6    27.5    24.3449186667   71.1314193333   5.39    288.3
25.4    27.60001    24.4019961667   71.8209758333   6.076   103.7
25.5    27.5    24.3473485  71.3570816667   6.762   95.3
25.5    27.5    24.3420308333   71.9577738333   5.978   103.7
25.6    27.29999    24.464413   71.993804   6.37    105.8
25.6    27.29999    24.3999401667   71.5558695  6.664   100.2
                           ...
```

Comment: Before we go into the solution, I want two things, 

1. Your matrices. Please post, your DataFrame. 
2. Are you sure you want to use Neural Network Regression?

Comment: if i use Neural Network Regression then Can I check the weight values? If that will can be, then it also  good.

Comment: You ARE using Neural Networks. I'm thinking about switching to a different library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if Neural Network is a right choice for this type of problem. I would suggest solving it with a linear regression. I would rather start getting familiar with a ***scikit-learn library*** and its algorithms for supervised learning. 
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html#supervised-learning
and ***pandas*** https://pandas.pydata.org/ for easy data pre-processing.
After you get a little bit more familiar with the libraries, try following this strategy:

1. Do the data set pre-processing (i.e. remove nans, unnecessary
   columns, scale your features)
2. Split your dataset into a training
   and test parts.
3. Try running several linear models (i.e
   LinearRegression, Ridge), try also improved validation schemes
   (KFold, StratifiedKFold)
4. Choose an appropriate metrics in order to validate your models

Scikit learn documentation should have all the
    necessary information. Good luck